# Time homogeneity and Markov property

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

My question may be related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183945/why-does-a-time-homogeneous-markov-process-possess-the-markov-property), but I couldn't figure out the connection. Anyway here we are: I'm learning about Markov chains from Rozanov's "Probability theory a concise course". In this book, a Markov chain is essentially defined to be a collection of discrete random variables $\xi(n)$ in discrete time, which satisfy time homogeneity, that is
$$\mathbb{P}(\xi(n+1)=\epsilon_j|\xi(n)=\epsilon_i) = \mathbb{P}(\xi(1)=\epsilon_j|\xi(0)=\epsilon_i)$$
for all $n$. Curiously the Markov property $$\mathbb{P}(\xi(n+1)=s|\xi(0),\xi(1),\dots,\xi(n)) = \mathbb{P}(\xi(n+1)=s|\xi(n))$$ is not stated in the hypothesis. So I was wondering if it is implied by the definition, i.e. if time homogeneity for Markov chains implies the Markov property.

Thank you.

---

PS : here is Rozanov's definition more explicitly :

*Consider a physical system with the following properties:*

*a) The system can occupy any of a finite or countably infinite number of 
states $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\dots$,*

*b) Starting from some initial state at time $t = 0$, the system changes its 
state randomly at the times $t = 1,2,\dots$. Thus, if the random variable 
$\xi(t)$ is the state of the system at time $t$, the evolution of the system in  time is described by the consecutive transitions (or "steps") 
$\xi(0)\to \xi(1) \to \xi(2) \to \cdots$*

*c) At time $t = 0$, the system occupies the state $\epsilon_i$ with initial probability $p_i^0=\mathbb{P}(\xi(0)=\epsilon_i)$, $i = 1,2,\dots$.*

*d) Suppose the system is in the state $\epsilon_i$ at any time $n$. Then the

probability that the system goes into the state $\epsilon_j$ at the next step is given by
$$p_{i,j} = \mathbb{P}(\xi(n + 1) =\epsilon_j | \xi(n) = \epsilon_i),$$ $i,j=1,2,\dots$ 
regardless of its behavior before the time $n$. The numbers $p_{i,j}$ called 
the transition probabilities, do not depend on the time n.*

*A "random process" described by this model is called a Markov chain.*

Comment: "regardless of its behavior before the time n" is the Markov property.

Comment: It seems to me that the only thing used throughout the chapter is that $p_{i,j}$ does not depend on $n$. So I have the same question, if you only have the info that $p_{i,j}$ is independent of $n$ and the process is thus time-homogeneous, does it imply you have the Markov property, or are there counter-examples ?

Comment: The implicit assumption is, informally, that the behavior of the process *only* depends on the $p_{ij}$.  This is what implies the Markov property - in fact, it *is* the Markov property.

Comment: Ok, thank you both for clearing this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z_n$ denote an iid random variables uniform on $\{0, 1\}$ and then define a sequence $$X_n = X_{n-1} + Z_n + Z_{n-1}.$$  Then it's easy to see this is time-homogeneous, but it doesn't have the Markov property, as knowledge of both $X_{n-1}, X_{n-2}$ could give information about $Z_{n-1}$ that couldn't have been determined without $X_{n-2}.$

More explicitly, $$P(X_n = 5 | X_{n-1}=5) = \frac{1}{4} \neq 0 = P(X_n = 5 | X_{n-1}=5, X_{n-2} = 3)$$