# Time homogenity + markov property imply time-homogenous markov property

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stationary-processes

I am trying to prove that [definition 17.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNiYR.jpg) + "certain time homogenity" imply [definition 17.3iii](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNiYR.jpg). In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183945/why-does-a-time-homogeneous-markov-process-possess-the-markov-property) post the vice versa (17.3iii implies 17.1) was shown. So I want to show that for any $s,t\in[0,\infty)$ it holds

$$P_x[X_{t+s}\in A|\mathcal{F}_s]=\kappa_t(X_s,A)=P_{X_s}[X_t\in A]$$

by using
$$P_x[X_{t+s}\in A|\mathcal{F}_s]=P_x[X_{t+s}\in A|X_s]$$

and a "certain time homogenity", which the author does not specify.

**I tried following:** Note that $P_x[X_0=x]=1$.

$$P_x[X_{t+s}\in A|\mathcal{F}_s]=P_x[X_{t+s}\in A|X_s]=P_x[X_t\in A|X_0]=P_{X_0}[X_t\in A]$$

But now, I do not know how to proceed. Also I do not know if, that's the right use of this "time homogenity", the author is writing about.

I would really appreciate some help on this one. Thanks in advance!